# pdb disfunctionality within spyder (python 3.5) Ipython console on windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, function, pickle, spyder, pdb

My code looks like

```
`import pdb
import pickle
........
def Abc(a,b):
    ********
    *****
def Xyz(**m):
    ****
    ****
getIt=pickle.load(open('Link to pickled data','rb')) # unpickling data
x=1
y=2
Abc(x,y) # calling functions
Z=3
Xyz(getIt)  # passing unpickled data 
pdb.set_trace()
m=3 # my expectation of pdb to start from`
```

As one can see, as I run this code, I should see instruction pointer at m=3 in Ipython console on spyder but
I am seeing the code is executing from 
x=1 (immediately after function definations)

**Please assist me to know why pdb.set_trace() is ignored by spyder within Ipython console**
I tried installing Ipdb but module wasnt recognized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) You're correct in that currently Spyder ignores `pdb.set_trace()`.

This is a bug and it will be fixed in Spyder **3.2** (to be released in June of 2017).